# LSTM Autoencoder Output Layer

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, autoencoder

I am trying to get a LSTM autoencoder to recreate its inputs. So far I have:

```
class getSequence(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        out, _ = x
        return out


class getLast(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        out, states = x
        states = states[len(states) - 1]
        return states

class AEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, first_layer, second_layer, n_layers):
        super(AEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.encode = nn.Sequential(nn.LSTM(input_size, first_layer, batch_first=True),
                                    getSequence(),
                                    nn.ReLU(True),
                                    nn.LSTM(first_layer, second_layer),
                                    getLast())
        self.decode = nn.Sequential(nn.LSTM(second_layer, first_layer),
                                    getSequence(),
                                    nn.ReLU(True),
                                    nn.LSTM(first_layer, input_size),
                                    getSequence())

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.float()
        x = self.encode(x)
        x = x.repeat(32, 1, 1) # repeating last hidden state of self.encode
        x = self.decode(x)
        return x
```

While researching I have been seeing some people adding a time-distributed dense layer at the end of the `self.decode`. I am confused if that final layer is specific to other tasks autoencoders are used for, if so, can I ignore that layer if I am only trying to recreate inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **time-distributed dense layer** as name suggested just an ordinary dense layer that apply to every temporal slice of an input, you can think it as special form of **RNN cell**, i.e without recurrent hidden state.

So you can using any layer that is time-distributed as your output layer for an Autoencoder that deal with time-distributed inputs, e.g RNN layer with **LSTM Cell**, **GRU Cell**, **Simple RNN Cell** or **time-distributed dense layer**; As in [research paper that propose the LSTM-Autoencoder](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.04681), it basic model for reconstruct sequence of  vectors (image patches or features) only using one LSTM layer in both encoder and decoder, model structure is:

[image]

Following is an example to using **time-distributed dense layer** in decoder:

```
class Decoder(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, seq_len, input_dim=64, n_features=1):
    super(Decoder, self).__init__()

    self.seq_len, self.input_dim = seq_len, input_dim
    self.hidden_dim, self.n_features = 2 * input_dim, n_features

    self.rnn = nn.LSTM(
      input_size=input_dim,
      hidden_size=self.hidden_dim,
      num_layers=1,
      batch_first=True)

    self.output_layer = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, n_features)

  def forward(self, x):
    x = x.repeat(self.seq_len, self.n_features)
    x = x.reshape((self.n_features, self.seq_len, self.input_dim))
    x, (hidden_n, cell_n) = self.rnn(x)
    x = x.reshape((self.seq_len, self.hidden_dim))
    return self.output_layer(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the paper reference and your answer. I will keep the structure of my model the same and output through the LSTM layer I have described above.

Comment: @Race Glad to help : )